# Assign key number to php array objects

Tags: php, arrays

My code

```
$str = array(fgets($da, 1024));
      
      print_r($str);
```

I'm trying to create an array in php from a dynamic output , but i noticed the keys in all object are [0], i need to assign a diferent key number to each object, how can i do that ?
Looks weird to me that all keys are 0, im trying to figure but nothing helps me.
Result :

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => 
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 200
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 819105 rs fs       
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 300 tert
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => THO   
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 91362               
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] =>     06-20-21  6:56 PM
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
    
    )
    
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
    
    
    Array
    (
        [0] =>   3   Cat            20   4.82     0.0   7.4     30
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] =>   4   Dogs                   19   26.2     0.8  7.1     62
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
    
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the input is reliable, you can split on whitespace for example:

```
$str = fgets($da, 1024);
$a = explode(" ", $str);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` with the `spread (...)` operator would work.

```
$str = array(fgets($da, 1024));
$str = array_merge(...$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the keys appear to be zero because you are wrapping each line from the file in its own array, so each array has one element at index zero.

If you define a buffer outside of your read loop, and add each line to it, each line will have its own index.

```php
$da = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

// Define a buffer for the output
$data = [];
while (($str = fgets($da)) !== false)
{
    // Add our line to the buffer
    $data[] = $str;
}

fclose($da);

print_r($data);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200

    [1] => 819105 rs fs

    [2] => 300 tert

    [3] => THO

    [4] => 91362

    [5] => 06-20-21  6:56 PM

    [6] => 3   Cat            20   4.82     0.0   7.4     30

    [7] => 4   Dogs                   19   26.2     0.8  7.1     62
)
```

But it looks like you may have some sort of header information in the first 6 lines of the file, maybe info from an HTTP request? Then lines that are somehow delimited, maybe by tab, but then the text got munged somewhere on the way into the SO post?

You can use a combination of fgets and [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv) to pull the data from the file and organize it into associative arrays.

Input:

```
200
819105 rs fs
300 tert
THO
91362
06-20-21  6:56 PM
3   Cat 20  4.82    0.0 7.4 30
4   Dogs    19  26.2    0.8 7.1 62
5   Wombat  20  4.20    0.0 6.9 30
6   Hedgehogs   19  26.2    0.8 7.1 62
```

```php
$da = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

// Define a buffer for the output
$data = [];

// Define the fields in the header, each header line needs an entry
$headerDef = [
    'status',
    'transfer_stats',
    'what_is_this',
    'something_else',
    'content_length',
    'timestamp'
];

// Define the columns in the data rows, each column needs an entry
$columnDef = [
    'id',
    'type',
    'count',
    'average_weight',
    'tax',
    'food_weight_percent_per_day',
    'fluffiness'
];

// Define an array to hold the header contents
$headerData = [];

// For each line in the header definition, extract a line from the file
while (!empty($headerDef) && $str = fgets($da, 1024))
{
    $currValue = trim($str);
    
    // Pull the next field from the front of the array
    $currHeaderField = array_shift($headerDef);
    
    // Set the entry in the header data array
    $headerData[$currHeaderField] = $currValue;
}

while ($row = fgetcsv($da, 1024, "\t"))
{
    // Create a new associative array by combining the column names and the row data
    $data[] = array_combine($columnDef, $row);
}

fclose($da);

print_r($headerData);
print_r($data);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 200
    [transfer_stats] => 819105 rs fs
    [what_is_this] => 300 tert
    [something_else] => THO
    [content_length] => 91362
    [timestamp] => 06-20-21  6:56 PM
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => Cat
            [count] => 20
            [average_weight] => 4.82
            [tax] => 0.0
            [food_weight_percent_per_day] => 7.4
            [fluffiness] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => Dogs
            [count] => 19
            [average_weight] => 26.2
            [tax] => 0.8
            [food_weight_percent_per_day] => 7.1
            [fluffiness] => 62
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [type] => Wombat
            [count] => 20
            [average_weight] => 4.20
            [tax] => 0.0
            [food_weight_percent_per_day] => 6.9
            [fluffiness] => 30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [type] => Hedgehogs
            [count] => 19
            [average_weight] => 26.2
            [tax] => 0.8
            [food_weight_percent_per_day] => 7.1
            [fluffiness] => 62
        )

)
```

Of course the field names are just made up, I have no idea what your actual data is. And I'm assuming that the data rows are delimited with tabs, that may not be the case. But you should be able to use this as a starting point.

PS. It could be that the HTTP data at the top of the file is included by mistake, perhaps from a curl request? You could change that with the CURLOPT_HEADER option and [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt)